# Can connect to mongodb atlas locally but not on live server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to deploy my first Node.js site to a live server and I am at the point where I am trying to run `npm start` in terminal. When it starts the process it looks like it's going to work but then after a while I get an error:

> Error connecting to db: failed to connect to server on first connect
>   [MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT] Failed at the start script.

I tried it again locally and it worked fine so the issue isn't my login credentials or IP address as I set mongodb to allow all IP addresses to connect.

In my package.json file I have the db details like so:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production MONGO_USER=myuser MONGO_PASSWORD=mypassword MONGO_DEFAULT_DATABASE=mydatabase node app.js",
    "start-server": "node app.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
```

So, I am unsure as to why I cannot connect to the database. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try connecting to the Mongo in your server start using async/await with an hard coded Mongo URL instead of passing the variables like this. I am not saying this is wrong, but I am only saying to see what happens if you hard code userID/pwd etc in server start up and connect.

Comment: @JBone, are you referring to the app.js file?

Comment: yes I assume your `  const server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(PORT, callbackFunc) ` is in your app.js that you are referring to

Comment: @RohitDalal No, the documentation said between 30000 and 50000. How do I check the port is open and does that have something to do with connecting to Mongo?

Comment: My bad the port should be 27017 and u can check by running telnet myserver.com 27017 command from terminal after connecting to the server.

Comment: The default port is 27017 for mongo db if it's not the case for u then first check if mongo server is even running or not. Use command - sudo service mongod status. One more advice do not put your creds on json or js file directly use dotenv package.

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. I didn't post that part of the error message because it has my cluster name in but that port you mentioned is what it is using `mongodb.net:27017`

Comment: Whats the output of   sudo service mongod status  and telnet command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187860/discussion-between-rohit-dalal-and-user8463989).